# Primavera switching computers master.mdf replace not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, primavera

I'm using primavera with a SQL Server database.

I switched computers, so I took with me the `primavera_DAT`, `primavera_LOG` files, then I installed primavera on the other computer and replaced the above files.

The issue is, whenever I enter primavera, I can establish the connection, but can not login and it is telling me the username and password are wrong.

I did some research and I found out that the usernames and passwords are stored in the `master.mdf` file.

I also have the `master.mdf` from the other computer, however when I replace them, I am getting the error whenever I start the SQL Server service from services.

How can I recreate the username or pass for the users (privuser, pubuser) that is, get the new `master.mdf` like the old one ??

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate the necessary logins from the users of your database using sp_change_users_login with 'Auto_fix' which will map existing logins and create new logins if they don't exist. The password has to be given and changed later for not existing logins.

```
Declare @Membername varchar(255)
Declare @SQl Varchar(8000)


Select @SQL=''
Create Table #tmp
(
DbRole varchar (255),
Membername varchar (255),
MemberSid uniqueIdentifier
)
insert into  #tmp exec sp_helprolemember
Delete from #tmp where Membername in ('sa','dbo','guest')
Delete from #tmp where Membername like ('db_%')


DECLARE P_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Distinct Membername from #tmp

OPEN P_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM P_cursor 
INTO @Membername

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   Select @SQL=@SQL + 'exec sp_change_users_login ''Auto_Fix'',  ''' + @Membername +'''  ,   NULL, '+'''B3r12-3x$098f6''' +Char(13)+Char(10) 
   FETCH NEXT FROM P_cursor 
   INTO @Membername
END

CLOSE P_cursor
DEALLOCATE P_cursor
Drop Table #tmp
--Print @SQL
Exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: where should I do this ?

Comment: after restoring your Database on the new server, with e.g. the enterprise manager connected to your database.